# displaying RGB8 encoded image in a browser

Tags: html, image, data-uri

Displaying jpeg and png images is rather easy, eg. src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{msg.payload}}" src="data:image/png;base64,{{msg.payload}}"

How to display RGB8 images using img src=?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RGB8 is a pixel format, and not a file format.

Does your data have an image header? In binary form, is it just a PNG or TIFF or some other file format, or do you only have raw pixel data? If you have a file in binary form, you can set the mime-type of the image to the appropriate type and use the base64 of the binary.

If you have, instead, only raw pixel data, you can draw it via canvas (or there might be a way to display RAW image data as an img tag with appropriate mimetype, but Im not aware of it)

Comment: I would love to know the appropriate mimitype, things will be very straightforward. here is my image header {"encoding": "rgb8", "height": 480, "header": {"stamp": {"secs": 1512063764, "nsecs": 106991999}, "frame_id": "camera_rgb_optical_frame", "seq": 1}, "step": 1920, "data": "base64"